# python new install showing error while loading shared libraries

Tags: centos, python, mod-python

i installed python2.6 before in

```
/ust/local/bin
```

but now i removed it and installed a new python2.6.4 in

```
/opt/python2.6
```

i installed from [the article](http://www.venkysblog.com/install-python264-modwsgi-and-django-on-cento)

but on mid way only where they say to check python it says

```
[root@domain ~]# python
 /opt/python2.6/bin/python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.6.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

but when i open

```
/opt/python2.6/lib
```

i can found this file. please tell me whats wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you compile python2.6 with `--prefix=/opt/python2.6`, the binaries will be installed at `/opt/python2.6/bin`, the libraries at `/opt/python2.6/lib`, ...

> /opt/python2.6/bin/python: error while loading shared libraries:
>   libpython2.6.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory

This error means that python is not looking at the path the file is in. So you need to add the library path to `/etc/ld.so.conf` file and activate it with `ldconfig`:

```
# echo "/opt/python2.6/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libpython2.6.conf
# ldconfig
```

Comment: thanks alot sir... saved my time.. but can you please explain what i was missing and what these lines do for ldconfig?

Comment: or link to any tutorial from where i can get answers to my question like this?

Comment: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html

Answer (score 1):

in Step 2 try add LDFLAGS with right path... for example

```
env LDFLAGS="-L/opt/python2.6/lib -R/opt/python2.6/lib" ./configure --prefix=/opt/python2.6 --with-threads --enable-shared
```